# EntityFramework Aggregate column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following problem: I'm using EntityFramework v5.0 code first approach for my C# project where user can select some fields from the object using GUI, for example: Customer class with Name, Phone, City properties, user can select any. I want to create SQL queries at runtime using SqlQuery method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117(v=vs.103).aspx), so I need to create the required Type at runtime, I managed to do so using Reflection.Emit for simple queries like `SELECT Name,City FROM Customers` (I create Type with Name and City string properties here). But how do I create properties for Aggregate functions? For example

```
SELECT Customers.Name, COUNT(Customers.City) 
FROM Customers 
GROUP BY Customers.Name
```

I tried creating property named 'Count_Customer_City' and dozens of others but I always get 0 in result in it, so it looks like I need no name it correctly and it will be filled by actual values, however I can't figure out the correct name (or maybe there's much better general approach)

Comment: Why don't you use LINQ method instead of using `SqlQuery`?

Comment: Your defeating the purpose of EF by doing this. Select what you need using Linq and project into the type that you need after they query, and/or build business domain objects to support your output.

Comment: What's wrong with getting a bit to many data _once_ and hide/show in the UI? In the end it can be far more responsive, because now you have to get all data again when the user only wants to see one more column. It looks good, but it is over-engineered. It may even be testimony of a lack of clear use cases and interaction design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it using `context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand().CreateReader()` method where I can set column names explicitly